# Is is authorized to expand the codomain of a function to be fitted into a commutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have two functions $A$ and $B$ which are defined over a particular alphabet $\Sigma$ as follows:

$A: \Sigma^{*} \rightarrow \Sigma^{*}$

$B: \Sigma^{*} \rightarrow (\Sigma\setminus\{x\})^{*}$, where $x \in \Sigma$.

In a compositional viewpoint, $A\circ B \neq B \circ A$, since the domains and codomains are not compatible; however, I'm wondering whether or not the codomain of $B$ can be extended to $\Sigma^{*}$. I mean, we clearly have $(\Sigma\setminus\{x\})^{*} \subseteq \Sigma^{*}$, so it is possible to say $B: \Sigma^{*} \rightarrow \Sigma^{*}$? Because the recent $B$ covers the functionality of the main $B$.

Comment: Let $i : (\Sigma \setminus \{ x \})^{\ast} \to \Sigma^{\ast}$ be the inclusion. Then instead of $B$ you can consider the function $i \circ B : \Sigma^{\ast} \to \Sigma^{\ast}$, which maybe you actually wanted to do all along. This is not the same function as $B$ because its codomain is different.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: So, is there any other way (say, valid manipulation of (co)domains) to realize the following match: $A \circ B = B \circ A$, or it's completely impossible?

Comment: Like I just said, you can consider $i \circ B$ instead of $B$, and then everything's fine.